# Photoshop UXP Developer Tool React and Executing Actions

Tags: reactjs, photoshop, photoshop-script, uxp-script

I am developing a UXP Panel for Photoshop using the uxp developer tool and uxp react starter kit.

-First of all, I had some problems with this starter kit regarding the webpack and js parser. It is using acorn-with-stage3 in resolutions option in package.json and it caused some errors when I add new npm packages probably because of dependency conflicts. So I was unable to add any library even Spectrum Web compenents. Then, I removed that resolution option for acorn and now I can run the plugin with new packages.However, now I am getting different errors, for example when I add the ColorWheel or Color Area React component from @react-spectrum/color. It creates the component but It cannot render it, gives black area or nothing. Also I am getting this error for Color Wheel from debuggin window of UXP developer tool:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3OA5.jpg)

My question related to this part is that, I think there is an issue with version of packages, probably related to webpack. Is there any guideline or new documentation or tutorial about developing UXP with React with more recent versions of libraries, also can removing the acorn-with-stage3 cause me any problems?

Secondly, I have a set of actions that I want to integrate with my panel. I used Alchemist Plugin from CreativeCloud to generate javascript code from my .atn action file. When I run the action from .atn file in Photoshop it is working as expected. However, when I use the generated code from my panel it gets stuck at some commands and gives "program error" without any error explanations. I tried to track the error location and I found one of them at a "make" command and one of them at a "move" command. I also tried with different configurations for action options such as syncExecution, modalBehaviour and nothing worked. Why can this happen? Can Alchemist generate the code incorrectly or some command options changed in new version of Photoshop? For the worst case scenario, is there a way to run the actions from files inside my react app? Thanks in advance.